# UPDATE table mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and it works fine when updating the  score and date. But it won't update the row's name or country. Does this have something to do with the php string??? Very confused!

```
$userName = "John";
$userCountry = "USA";
$lowestScoreId =  99;
$userPoints = 500;


include 'config.php';


$currentTime = time();

mysql_query("UPDATE highScores SET name = $userName WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");
mysql_query("UPDATE highScores SET score = $userPoints WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");
mysql_query("UPDATE highScores SET country =$userCountry WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");
mysql_query("UPDATE highScores SET date = $currentTime WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");
```

Comment: Is the MySQL table field set properly? varchar
?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the values you set. And you can do that in 1 query.

```
UPDATE highScores
SET `name`    = '$userName',
    `score`   = '$userPoints',
    `country` = '$userCountry',
    `date`    = '$currentTime'
WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in one statement.

```
$userName = "John";
$userCountry = "USA";
$lowestScoreId =  99;
$userPoints = 500;

include 'config.php';

$currentTime = time();

mysql_query("UPDATE highScores SET name = '$userName', score = '$userPoints', country = '$userCountry', date = '$currentTime' WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you shouldn't use the PHP mysql_ functions anymore. Have a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) which is newer, faster and has more features.

Comment: Or, for that matter, you could use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php - it's similar to MySQLi but has the advantage of supporting databases other than MySQL